# Visualforce security and permission sets

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have created a visualforce page and in the permission set I have given the access to District Managers. However, what I want is that when a particular district manager views the VF page, he should be able to see charts and data only for his district. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: when you write your VF Page do you have a custom controller, setting with sharing ie public class with sharing class_name{...}(https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm) will reflect the sharing rules for the current user. Please clarify how the VF page is designed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply rao. I think I follow you. Just for the clarification, my current controller statement looks like this: `Public with sharing class ABCControllerfinal {` Should this take care of it?

Comment: meaning the viewing user would be able to see data for only the district under him?

Comment: can you paste your page, are there sharing rules present on sobject referenced as the standard controller in your page. If there are sharing rules the with sharing should take care of the data restriction.

Comment: I am using a sobject called User Stats, and I just checked the sharing rules for it. It says `Public Read/Write`. Also in my VF page I am using a custom controller not the standard controller.

Comment: Typically how we have set up the salesforce is that the reports that are generated out of these sobjects have permission sets of My Team etc. but otherwise the sobjects itself have sharing setting of `Public Read/Write`

Comment: if the sharing rules are public read/ write there is no restriction on the data. The permission set/ security settings only control the object access/ page access (ie) who can read,create, update, edit, access to object is controlled by the PS and security on page only controls who has access to the page. To control the data visibility if you do not have sharing rules on the object you need to control the data based on profile and adjust your SOQL queries based on profile ( not a suggested approach,but if there is no sharing rule controlling soql would be the option As far I know).

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help. As much as I would want to change the sharing settings for the sobect, I don't think I can do that (as there are many pages and reports that are built on it and changing the setting might break some of these). Can you guide me on where can I learn more about the soql path and adding rules based on viewer's profile?  (let me know if we can move this discussion to chat)